# How many ways to arrange?

Tags: combinatorics

Here's a question that I am confused on.

How many ways are there to arrange n items if m of them are defective and n-m are normal? Normal and defective are otherwise indistinguishable. When there is no requirement regarding the arrangement, How many ways are there?

For instance, if there are 4 items and 2 are defective and other 2 are normal. Then, NNDD NDND NDDN DNDN DDNN DNND are all possible arrangements.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a close look at an example:

NDNNND is a possible arrangement of defective and normal items. If the normal and defective numbers were numbered, the number of different arrangements preserving the NDNNND arrangement would be:

$1$(the arr. at hand)$\cdot 4!$(different arr. of normal items)$\cdot2!$(different arr. of defective items)

Let's come backwards from this.

Let's denote the answer to your question with $n=6$ and $m=2$ with $k$. When there are 2 defective and 4 normal items, the number of total different arrangements would be $k\cdot 2!\cdot4!$, which is also $n!$ because there are $n!$ ways to arrange $n$ different items.

I would encourage you to go on yourself from here to generalize. However, the answer is written below.

> When generalized, the equation becomes $n! = k_{n,m} \cdot m! \cdot (n-m)! $, and the answer to your question, $k_{n,m} = \dfrac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$

Comment: I set your answer up as a spoiler if that's ok...figured that'd be better than using white space

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The number of arrangements is the same as the number of ways to [choose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $m$ slots  (for the defective items in your setup) from $n$ total slots, which is ${n\choose m}=\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$